# AngularJS - semicolon after $scope function expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope, function-expression

With JavaScript, it's best practice to use semicolons after a function expression block:

```
var myfunction = function() {
    alert('hello world');
};
```

What about in AngularJS, say in a controller, using the dreaded `$scope`?
Often times I see these written without semicolons after the closing block:

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

But does anyone know the best practice for this? Will adding a semicolon at the end of these $scope 'expressions' break my AngularJS app? Like so:

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    alert('hello world');
};
```

Comment: AngularJS is just a javascript framework. You are free to use or not use a semicolon and this will largely be a matter of personal preference and opinion.

Comment: To tack on to @Lex comment, find whatever you're comfortable with and use a linter to enforce.

Answer (score -1):

I almost always don't use a semi colon when declaring a `function`. Regardless of it's a normal Javascript function or a AngularJS function. This is my preference and the preference of many others, but I would go by the current coding standards of what you are currently working on. If it uses `;` then use them also **to be consistent**. If you are working alone, then do what feels comfortable for you.

What I do realize though is that it can be quite confusing to keep track of all the `{}` when inside an AngularJS controller which has objects in it also. What to remember to do is always add a `;` when you finish declaring an object. Something I overlook sometimes when I see

`$scope.something = ...`

I overlook it sometimes thinking it's a `function` but can really be an `object`. For example,

```
var MyController = function($scope) {
    $scope.Obj = {
        name: 'Foo' 
    }; // Don't forget me!

    $scope.DoSomething = function(param) {
        $scope.Obj = {
            name: param
        }; // Don't forget me!
    }
}
```

This is just something I have come across in my code and in seeing others.